# Is there a particular ID given to the terminals(Command Prompt) i opened in Linux Machine

Tags: command-line

I have opened 2 or more terminals opened in Linux system. I want to differentiate them... Is there is a way to differentiate them???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `tty` command to find out which device file corresponds to your current terminal.

> tty - print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input

It should usually respond with a path in the form

- `/dev/ttyX` (X in range 1-6) if you are in a real TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1 - F6</kbd>), or
- `/dev/pty/X` (X >= 0) if you are in a pseudo-TTY, which is usually the case for terminal emulators like `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` as well as remote shell connections via `ssh`.

These file descriptors clearly identify your current terminal. There are no two terminals with the same ID at a time, but the IDs become free again once you close one and might be reused by the next terminal you open.